# Use of select or multithread for almost 80 or more clients?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select

I am working on one project in which i need to read from 80 or more clients and then write their o/p into a file continuously and then  read these new data for another task. My question is what should i use select or multithreading?

Also I tried to use multi threading using read/fgets and write/fputs call but as they are blocking calls and one operation can be performed at one time so it is not feasible. Any idea is much appreciated.

update 1:  I have tried to implement the same using condition variable. I able to achieve this but it is writing and reading one at a time.When another client tried to write then it cannot able to write unless i quit from the 1st thread. I do not understand this. This should work now. What mistake i am doing?

Update 2: Thanks all .. I am able to succeeded to get this model implemented using mutex condition variable.

updated Code is as below:

```
        **header file*******
         char    *mailbox ;
    pthread_mutex_t  lock  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER ;
    pthread_cond_t   writer = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
      pthread_t          t1 , t2;
      pthread_attr_t     attr;
      int            fd, sock , *newfd;
      struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
      socklen_t      clilen;
      void          *read_file();
      void          *update_file();

      //making a server socket
      if((fd=make_server(atoi(argv[1])))==-1)
        oops("Unable to make server",1)


      //detaching threads
      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
      pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

      ///opening thread for reading
      pthread_create(&t2,&attr,read_file,NULL);

      while(1)
      {
        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        //accepting request
        sock=accept(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);

        //error comparison against failire of request and INT
        if(sock==-1 && errno != EINTR)
                oops("accept",2)
        else if ( sock ==-1 && errno == EINTR)
            oops("Pressed INT",3)

        newfd = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *newfd = sock;
        //creating thread per request
        pthread_create(&t1,&attr,update_file,(void *)newfd);
      } 
     free(newfd);
     return 0;
    }

    void *read_file(void *m)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        while(1)
        {
            printf("Waiting for lock.\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&writer,&lock);
            printf("I am reading here.\n");
            printf("%s",mailbox);
            mailbox = NULL ;
        pthread_cond_signal(&writer);
        }
    }


    void *update_file(int *m)
    {
       int  sock = *m;
       int  fs ; 
       int  nread;
       char buffer[BUFSIZ] ;

       if((fs=open("database.txt",O_RDWR))==-1)
          oops("Unable to open file",4)

       while(1)
       {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        write(1,"Waiting to get writer lock.\n",29);

        if(mailbox != NULL)
           pthread_cond_wait(&writer,&lock);

            lseek(fs,0,SEEK_END);
            printf("Reading from socket.\n");
            nread=read(sock,buffer,BUFSIZ);
            printf("Writing in file.\n");
            write(fs,buffer,nread);
            mailbox = buffer ;
          pthread_cond_signal(&writer);
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
       }
        close(fs);
    }
```

Comment: 80 clients isn't many, nothing actually. I would use threads until proven you need more scalability.

Comment: And I don't see why you need any of those `fseek()` calls. You're just reading the file sequentially. You don't need to clear the buffer either.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Need not use fseek. I am  now trying to use buffer in write thread and by using condition variable i am trying to read it in read thread. I suppose by this i can avoid to open file again. I am also figuring out if i can use send/recvfrom call instead of read/write to avoid blocking from several clients. What do you say about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the the networking portion of things, either thread-per-client or multiplexed single-threaded would work fine.

As for the disk I/O, you are right that disk I/O operations are blocking operations, and if your data throughput is high enough (and/or your hard drive is slow enough), they can slow down your network operations if the disk I/O is done synchronously.

If that is an actual problem for you (and you should measure first to verify that it *really is* a problem; no point complicating things if you don't need to), the first thing I would try to ameliorate the problem would be to make your file's output-buffer larger by calling [setbuffer](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html).  With a large enough buffer, it may be possible for the C runtime library to hide any latency caused by disk access.

If larger buffers aren't sufficient, the next thing I'd try is creating one or more threads dedicated to reading and/or writing data.  That is, when your network thread wants to save data to disk, rather than calling fputs()/write() directly, it allocates a buffer containing the data it wants written, and passes that buffer to the IO-write thread via a (mutex-protected or lockless) FIFO queue.  The I/O thread then pops that buffer out of the queue, writes the data to the disk, and frees the buffer.  The I/O thread can afford to be occasionally slow in writing because no other threads are blocked waiting for the writes to complete.  Threaded reading from disk is a little more complex, but basically the IO-read thread would fill up one or more buffers of in-memory data for the network thread to drain; and whenever the network thread drained some of the data out of the buffer, it would signal the IO-read thread to refill the buffer up to the top again.  That way (ideally) there is always plenty of input-data already present in RAM whenever the network thread needs to send some to a client.

Note that the multithreaded method above is a bit tricky to get right, since it involves inter-thread synchronization and communication; so don't do it unless there isn't any simpler alternative that will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.Slowness is not an issue, i can afford to have some delay. I need to write data into the file so that some other work can be done on this. So i suppose large buffer option won't work. Also as server needs to read from several client so if i use separate thread to read and write then it also cause blocking. May be i wrong or lost. honestly i am scared. This is first big lab project am handling. Any link or sample code to explain your concept will help me more than anything...

Comment: If you don't need optimum performance, then you might as well keep things simple and do your file I/O from the network thread.  File I/O operations may block, but never for very long, so it's probably not an issue.  Keeping everything in one thread will help avoid race conditions (e.g. when thread A is reading from the file while thread B is writing to it, thread A might see half-updated data which can cause problems)

Answer (score 0):

Either select/poll or multithreading is ok if you you program solves the problem.

I' guess your program would be io-bound as the number of clients grows up, as you have disk read/write frequently. So it would not speed up to have multiple threads doing the io operation. Polling may be a better choice then

Comment: Thanks Tristan. I will try with select/poll as well but i will try to use multi threading first though i am bit nervous for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a socket that you get from `accept` to be non-blocking. Then it is easy to use `select` to find out when there is data, read the number of bytes that are available and process them.

With (only) 80 clients, I see no reason to expect any significant difference from using threads unless you get very different amounts of data from different clients.